# How to align div horizontally in React JS?

Tags: css, reactjs

Below is just a snippet of my code:

```
return(
     <div className='row'>
         <div>row1</div><div>row2</div><div>row3</div>
     </div>
);
```

I tried this, but it displays in vertical. Image attached below

[image]

Comment: this is not related to reactjs, you need to apply css properties to achieve this.

Comment: This is a CSS issue. Take a look at css flexbox or css grid, either of which shoud allow you to do what you're attempting.

Comment: Mayank. I saw that answer previously. This is related to react js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing to do with React, but CSS :

```
 <div className='rows'>
     <div className='row'>row1</div>
     <div className='row'>row2</div>
     <div className='row'>row3</div>
 </div>
```

One way to do it, in your CSS :

```
 .rows .row {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: thanks. that help. I tried something like this


 `return(<div >
                 <div style={{ display:'inline-block'}}>row1 </div>
                 <div style={{ display:'inline-block'}}>row2 </div>
                 <div style={{ display:'inline-block'}}>row3 </div>
                 </div>);`  That worked

Answer (score 6):

It is not Reactjs problem. use CSS to do that. `display:inline`

```
 display: flex
```

```css
div{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div className='row'>
     <div>row1</div><div>row2</div><div>row3</div>
</div>
```

OR use `display:inline`

```css
div{
    display: inline
}
```

```html
<div className='row'>
    <div>row1</div><div>row2</div><div>row3</div>
</div>
```